# Accessing Italian World War I records online?

Tags: military-records, world-war-1, italy

Is there a way to access Italian war records pertaining to individual soldiers (I'm looking specifically for World War I) online?

For example, I know Australia does but my somewhat limited knowledge of Italian didn't get me far with my searches.

Comment: Hi tschumann, welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE. When you say "war records", what exactly do you mean? Service records pertaining to individual soldiers? Logs of battalion movements? Casualty lists? If you could be a bit more specific about your goal (i.e. what information you are hoping to find), I'm sure you will get an answer that will be much more useful to you.

Comment: @HarryVervet I've updated the question.

Comment: Hello i am trying to spread the word on obtaining my paternal and maternal grandfathers military records. i know they both served in the battle of caporetto of ww1. i have tried several avenues and im not giving up on obtaining these records it will tell us all so much on what he did in that war. any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated. even if you can pass this message to others. i have both of their names, and the dob, town in which they were born, their parents names, thank you for your help.

Comment: @MikeRegina Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  I hope that you will click the [ask] button to ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Military Records (Foglio) are kept by region.  You need to know which region or province your ancestors were born. My father was born in Teramo Province. I sent an email (in Italian) to the Teramo Archive Military District (most provincial or regional archives have an internet presence) with name, date of birth, town of birth and names of parents. Less than three weeks later they sent a copy of his military folder showing when he registered for he draft, when he was called to active duty and his unit(s) of assignment.  This record also showed his military awards be they personal or to the unit while he was a member.  Then it showed his discharge date and place and type (honorable etc). Once you have the unit designation you can search for battles that unit was in using Brigade or regiment histories.  These are easy to find on the internet, although you might need to translate from the Italian.

Answer (score 1):

For those seeking Italian Military Records a good starting place may be the [Italy Military Records](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Italy_Military_Records) wiki page of FamilySearch.

This leads to at least one online resource, [Albo dei Caduti della Grande Guerra](http://www.cadutigrandeguerra.it/Default.aspx) (Roll of the Great War Memorial):

> The publication of the Golden of the Great War Memorial wants to be a
>   renewed honor the sacrifice of those who fought and fell in the first
>   world war of the twentieth century. The memory of them is imperishable
>   and living reminder to the younger generation.
>
> In this database on this website you can see the cards of all the
>   Fallen contained in 28 volumes more 'the three appendices of the
>   Veneto constituting the Roll of Honour

I do not speak Italian but with the help of [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com.au/) I was able to easily start to access its records via its Cerca Nominativo (Name Search) link where I typed in a surname and hit Cerca (Search).