# Seeking World War 1 service record for Italian Army cook from Collessano, Sicily?

Tags: world-war-1, army, italy

AI am looking for family records for Gioacchino Misita, who was a cook in the Italian Army in WWI.

He was from Collessano, Sicily.  He was shot in the leg.

How can I access his service record?

I do not read Italian so I am at a great disadvantage.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  I think the place to start here is by trying to find Gioacchino's WW1 service record, because that may tell you something about his family like his next of kin.

Comment: See also: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12125/